# Removing Fragment with Animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-fragmentactivity

I am working like the below written code for my application:-

Step 1: Fragment Activity -> Added Fragment A on it at the time of launching the activity using the following code.

```
        Fragement_Home home = new Fragement_Home();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameContent, home).commit();
```

Step 2: After that I want another fragment on it sliding from upside down on the previous fragment, for that I wrote the following code:

```
   FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        Fragment_Menu next = new Fragment_Menu();

            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_down, R.anim.slide_up);
            ft.add(R.id.frameContent, next);
            ft.addToBackStack("Menu");
            ft.show(next);
            ft.commit();
```

Animation occurred as desired. But when I want to remove the "NEXT" fragment that was added in Step 2, the animation is not showing at all. I want to show it now from downside to UPside.

Step 3: To Remove the Fragment that was added in Step 2

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down);
                ft.remove(next);
                ft.commit();
                fm.popBackStack();
```

The Fragment is removed at once, and no animation is occurring at all. Kindly let me where I am wrong, I have tried several times.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this function. Here you can set animation for popping from back stack

**setCustomAnimations (int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit)**

As Documentation describes it as..

> Set specific animation resources to run for the fragments that are entering and exiting in this transaction. The popEnter and popExit animations will be played for enter/exit  operations specifically when popping the back stack.

Comment: Thanks @Panther. But it has not helped me at all.